# Executing Bower in a CI Environment, such as Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, build-process, bower

My Jenkins is running on `CentOS 6` with `node.js 0.10.15` and `bower 1.0.3`.

I have a shell task which executes the following:

```
npm install
bower install
grunt clean package
```

The bower installation fails when building:

```
+ bower install

path.js:360
        throw new TypeError('Arguments to path.join must be strings');
              ^
TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings
    at path.js:360:15
    at Array.filter (native)
    at Object.exports.join (path.js:358:36)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/
                           update-notifier/node_modules/configstore/configstore.js:9:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)

Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

When I'm executing `bower install` in a terminal while logged in as the Jenkins user, it works. The other mentioned commands work as expected (`npm`, `grunt`).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that your execution environment has neither `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` nor `$HOME` set as environment variables.

You can work around this by manually setting it, for example, to the current workspace:

```
export XDG_CONFIG_HOME="$WORKSPACE/.config"
...
bower install
```

Comment: Thank you, I setted the HOME environment variable in Jenkins and it works now. Here the link to this problem on Github: https://github.com/yeoman/configstore/pull/7